# What is the best approach to get a millisecond-rounded timestamp string in Howard Hinnant's Date library?

Tags: c++, date, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I have the following code, using Date library:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << now;
    std::string nowStr = ss.str();   // I need a string
    std::cout << nowStr << " UTC\n";
}
```

The result is:

```
2020-03-26 17:38:24.473372486 UTC
```

Is stringstream the correct approach to obtain a string from the chrono::timepoint that now() returns? And, if so, how can I round those nanoseconds to milliseconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `ostringstream` is a good way to do this.  You could also use `date::format` which returns a `string`, but this still uses a `ostringstream` internally:

```
string s = format("%F %T %Z", now);
```

With either technique, you can truncate to `milliseconds` output by truncating the input `time_point` to `milliseconds` prior to formatting it.  You can choose any of these rounding modes:

- round towards the epoch date:  `time_point_cast<milliseconds>(now)`
- round towards the past : `floor<milliseconds>(now)`
- round towards the future : `ceil<milliseconds>(now)`
- round towards the nearest (towards even on tie):  `round<milliseconds>(now)`

-

```
string s = format("%F %T %Z", floor<milliseconds>(now));

2020-03-26 17:38:24.473 UTC
```

In C++20 this will become:

```
string s = format("{:%F %T %Z}", floor<milliseconds>(now));
```